# Elementary way to see that $S_1$ has only one smooth structure

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is there any elementary way to see that $S_1$ has only one smooth structure?

By the classification of the one dimensional manifold, we know that the $1$-dim manifolds are only $R, R_+, [0,1], S_1$. Therefore, if $S_1$ has another structure that agrees on the topology, then it is still a connected closed 1-manifold, which, simply by topological argument, can be only $S_1$ among the four categories.

However, the proof of the category is not simple, and I'm curious if there is any other simpler proof for the statement.

Comment: This is described in one of the exercise in Lee (Exercise 15-13).

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you're trying to talk about the classification of one-dimensional topological manifolds or already reference the classification of one-dimensional smooth manifolds.

Comment: It's the classification of one-dimensional topological manifolds

Comment: I do not think the information that the smooth manifold is homeomorphic to $S^1$ helps in any way.